# regular expression to get the name of java file

Tags: java, regex

I hava a code like this

```
theResult.setFile(fileNode.getText().toUpperCase());
```

that gives me an output a path of a file in my drive like this.

```
D:\workspace\try\myFile.java
```

How can regex just give me the name of my file ?
So, in output just show

```
myFile.java
```

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have the file path only in text, or do you actually have the file (File object)?

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "D:\\workspace\\try\\myFile.java";
String name = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
```

Comment: This will include \ in name. do `text.lastIndexOf("\\")+1` to remove it.(_BTW Not a Downvoter_)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
/^.*\\(.*?.java)$/
```

The code would become:

```
theResult.setFile(fileNode.getText().toUpperCase()).replaceFirst("^.*\\\\(.*?.java)$", "$1");
```

Regex parsers reads lines based on modifiers very sensitively. On `.*` this matches the entire line, where it sees `\\` (literal `\`) it backtracks to the **last backslash in line**, so everything after that is our file name when and only when it matches *"something.java"*. `.*?` is a non-greedy match, meaning instead of eating the whole word it reads character by character until it hits `.java`. It is captured in a capture group `( )` and we retrieve it with `$1` (Capture group 1).

View a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/eQ3iM1/1).

Comment: Why jump into such a griddy thing when we already have some handy solutions.?

Comment: @TAsk OP specifies regex, so even though it's a suboptimal approach it's still worth having an answer in regular expressions.

Comment: Yes you are right but,isn't it quite hard for some newbie to understand `regExp`? BTW +1 for your answer.